# TFS User needs permission to update build information

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Like I already asked in [Visual Studio Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7c49aa42-1cdf-404e-b0b6-4d67c0429f9a/user-needs-permission-to-update-build-information?forum=tfsadmin),
I wrote an application that binds work items to builds based on svn logs. When I try to hit `buildDetail.Information.Save();` I get the Exception User (Bob) needs permission to update build information.

[image: Error Log]

This user got the right permission set in the build permission dialog and I also set it in the admin command line on the tfs itself

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools\tfssecurity /a+ Build ProjectName UpdateBuildInformation n:ourDomain\bob ALLOW /collection:http://tfs-test:8080/tfs/Test
```

[image: Permission set in Build Tab]

[image: Command line permission set]

ToyStory is the name of the test project.

Last but not least: Bob is a Service Account.

[image: Prove Service Account]

What am I still missing that I get these messages? The VsoAgent.exe is running as Service on our BuildMashine as Bob and sure I restartet everything a couple of times. We are on all last updates for TFS 2015U1 and Windows Server 2008 R2. All Enterprise licenses. Date today: 22.03.2016

Update: Now I'm on the new R2 for TFS and I have still no clue why this is not working. Also there is still no proper REST function to set bound work items to that build

Comment: What do you mean by "binds work items to builds "? Link the work item to build?

Comment: exactly, it is retrieving the workitem-number(s) from the svn log and then tries to bind it to the build.

Answer (score 0):

Check the groups that Bob belongs to, to see whether there is a Deny or Not Set permission for the groups.

Comment: No on every group he belongs to it is set to allow

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to update a vNext build which is not fully supported by TFS API. The TFS API is designed to use with XAML build. So if you use it with vNext build, you may see some unexpected issues.

To attach a workitem to a build, you need to do update the information from workitem. Add a build link to the workitem and specify the build number. After this, you will see the associated work items in the build summary. You could use this API: [Add a link.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#add-a-link)

Comment: Why can I use save if it is not implemented? What does he try there then?

Comment: I tried using the REST API but there is no way to update the build properly. Do you have a different approach?

Comment: @Greaka What property you'd like to update? And I have updated my answer for how to link a workitem to build. Sorry for the incorrect information before.